# Printing triangle problems

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to print a triangle in the following format:

```
Enter the number of lines : 5
     *
     **
     ***
     ****
    *****
```

(The formatting isn't allowing me to center it to make a triangle but u get the point)

The following is what I go so far. It's not compiling. any help would be appreciated.

```
package trainagkes; 

import java.util.Scanner;

public class triangle {
    public static void leftTriangle()
    {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in)) {
            System.out.print("How many rows: ");
            int rows = input.nextInt();
            for (int x = 1; x <= rows; x++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void rightTriangle()
    {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in)) {
            System.out.print("How many rows: ");
            int rows = input.nextInt();
            for (int x = 1; x <= rows; x++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i >= x; i--)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println("*");    
            }
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
}
```

Comment: what compiler error are you getting?

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {
}` does not look like it will do anything.

Comment: If I import `Scanner` it compiles